# How do I search Google Docs by filename (or better, pattern matching filename)?

Tags: google-drive

A synchronisation bug in Google Drive has caused it to treat all my local files as duplicates. So I ended up with a bunch of extra: `filename(1)` that eat up 10's of GB of space.

How do I search for all of those on my Google Drive (via the web interface) and remove them?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a specific filename with something like the below image shows using:

[image: Search for filename]

You can then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the files displayed and remove them.

That's the best idea I can think of from the web interface side.